# Grammar Question: Trovi or Trovas?

Tags: verbs

On Duolingo I got a question wrong because I used *trovas* instead of *trovi*; then, I got the next one wrong because I did the opposite.

When should I use *trovi* and when should I instead use *trovas*?

Comment: Do you remember what the sentences were?

Comment: It would help to have the sentences you got wrong, because there is very little actual context to your question. If it's ok with you, could you mention one of the languages you regularly use? It doesn't have to be your native language.

Answer (score 4):

*trovas* is what you would normally use. The *-as* ending means that it is in the present tense. For example:

> I find trees in the garden -> Mi *trovas* arbojn en la ĝardeno

You would use *trovi* in cases where it is being used in combination with another verb. This is called the *infinitive*. In English the infinitive is sometimes the *to* form (like *to find*) and sometimes the *-ing* form (like *finding*). For example:

> I like finding trees -> Mi ŝatas *trovi* arbojn

In this case the main verb is *ŝatas*. That one is in the present tense so it ends with *-as*. The second verb *trovi* doesn’t have its own tense and it’s only used in conjuction with the main verb. Therefore it is in the infinitive and it ends with *-i*.